# WebSocket в JavaScript, ошибка при подключении

Tags: javascript, сервер, websocket, сокеты

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу по 77 порту с помощью такого кода:

```
  <script>
    alert("start!");
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.190/77");
    alert(exampleSocket.readyState);
  </script>
```

Выходит сначало start, а потом 0.
Пробую так:

```
  <script>
    alert("start!");
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.190:77");
    alert(exampleSocket.readyState);
  </script>
```

Выходит только start.
Одновременно с выполнением скрипта смотрю в вывод сервера, сообщений о подклюении нету, серверная часть точно рабочая.

Comment: оберните последний алерт в сеттаймаут, на пару секунд

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){alert(exampleSocket.readyState) },2000)`

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, алерта также нету, и соеденения к серверу тоже.

Comment: попробуйте порт поменять

Comment: Заработало, спасибо)